# Need to find entries in one excel column that are not in a different column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 4 excel columns two contain product identifying codes (columns A and D) and the other two contain the corresponding stock quantity.

I need to identify all entries that are in A not D and vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simple, follow below steps.
1. select Column D and A. use conditional formatting, and select the option to check duplicates.
2. Filter out the cells without color coding. they are the data points which doesn't repeat.

Hope this works.

Thanks,
Ved

Comment: What if there is a duplicate product in the same list and not in the other?

Comment: Thats great. First add a id to tag which column it belongs too. So its like, for a data point from Column A, add a text called Col-A. And for Column b Col-B. use concatenate formula to do this. then do a duplicate check.. it will work out.. hopefully...

Comment: So if you're going to add helper columns with concatenate, why not just use the same helper column to look up the value from the other list, and avoid the conditional formatting altogether?

Comment: Thanks! In the end I found using Vlookups solved the problem